# Extending QSettings to load / store Application settings

Tags: qt

I'm trying to persist some application specific info in a settings file.  Info like form size and position, the state of some check boxes on the main form etc.  I trying to extend the QSettings class to do this.

This is what I have so far:

appsettings.h

```
class AppSettings : public QSettings
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit AppSettings(QObject *parent = 0);

    void load();
    void save();

    bool getLinkState();
    bool getFullState();

    void setLinkState(bool state);
    void setFullState(bool state);


signals:

public slots:

private:
    int mainTop;
    int mainLeft;
    int mainWidth;
    int mainHeight;
    bool cbFullState;
    bool cbLinkState;
}
```

appsettings.cpp

```
#include "appsettings.h"

#include <QDebug>>

AppSettings::AppSettings(QObject *parent) :
    QSettings(parent)
{
    load();
}

void load(){
  qDebug() << "appSettings load()"" ;

}

void save() {
  qDebug() << "appSettings save()"" ;
}

bool getLinkState() {
  return cbLinkState;
}

bool getFullState() {
    return cbFullState;
}

void setLinkState(bool state)
{
    if (state == cbLinkState) return;

    cbLinkState = state;
    save();
}

void setFullState(bool state)
{
    if (state == cbFullState) return;

    cbFullState = state;
    save();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp
    AppSettings *appSettings = AppSettings("MyOrgName", "MyAppName);

```
cbLink->setChecked( appSettings->getLinkState() );
```

I'm unsure how to:

1) create the object in the mainwindow such that the organsiation name and application name get passed through to QSettings that I've inherited from.  I get a "no matching function" compile error on the first line in the mainwindow code above.

2) if I use the AppSettings class to store (cache) the info, how to create it only once and make it available from other windows and classes.  For example, I may want to store the location of other windows as well as the main window.

Comment: Why don't you just use QSettings as it was designed, to store and retrieve the data you need? How do you benefit from deriving from it here?

Comment: The documentation clearly describes how to store user-specific and application-specific settings using the native QSettings class

Comment: @Merlin: One of the benefits of having my own AppSettings class is that it can allow me to have windows that are agnostic to the storage method.  For example, I may want to store the appsettings in a SQLite database in the future.  If I use QSettings directly,  I have to change code wherever I use QSettings.  If I use my own class, I only have to change the code in that class.

Comment: @Bowdzone:  I have QSettings saving and retrieving data just fine.  That's not my problem here.

Comment: Why not simply wrap up the QSettings class? Aggregate, rather than inherit. This will enable you to change the underlying storage mechanism, while keeping the same API available to the other classes. In OO, inheritance is for extending the behaviour of a class by adding new functionality. I suggest creating your own Settings class as an abstract base and then derive from that the type of underlying mechanism you want to use; e.g. QtSettings, SQLSettings etc. Window classes then use a Settings base class pointer to call polymorphic functions, not caring about how it's implemented.

Comment: Merlin069 is right, composition beats inheritance.

Comment: OK - please can someone show me what the code might look like for aggregate / composition of the settings class?